# How to correctly align 16x16 icons to MenuItems in TPopupMenu?

Tags: delphi, icons, menuitem, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I use 16x16 pixel icons in a `TPopupMenu.` Unfortunately, the icons are not correctly aligned vertically to the `TMenuItem` caption:

[image]

[image]

This looks ugly. How can I align the icons correctly?

These are the Manifest settings from the Project Options:

[image]

Here is the source code of the project files to reproduce the problem:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.ImageList, Vcl.ImgList,
  Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ilMenus: TImageList;
    PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu;
    menuitem1: TMenuItem;
    menuitem2: TMenuItem;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Here is the form file:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 269
  ClientWidth = 454
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -12
  Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
  Font.Style = []
  PopupMenu = PopupMenu1
  Position = poScreenCenter
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 15
  object ilMenus: TImageList
    ColorDepth = cd32Bit
    DrawingStyle = dsTransparent
    Left = 18
    Top = 16
    Bitmap = {
      494C010101000800040010001000FFFFFFFF2110FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF424D3600
      0000000000003600000028000000400000001000000001002000000000000010
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00001F170D2D6D4D2E979E7041DBB6804BFCB27D49F69D6F41DA71502E9C2318
      0D30000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060502096E4D
      2D98B6814CFDB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB681
      4CFD72512F9F0906030C00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004030106876038BCB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFF8F653BC60705030A000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006C4C2D96B8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF71502E9C000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000001F160C2CB6804BFCB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB7814CFE251A0E330000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000000000067492B8FB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF72512F9F0000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000009B6E40D7B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFA17243E00000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000B37F4AF9B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000B37F4AF9B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB47F4BFA0000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000009B6E40D7B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFA07142DE0000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000000000068492A90B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF735230A00000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000001F160C2CB6814CFDB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF0000000000000000B8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF281D10380000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006D4D2E97B8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFF735230A0000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004030106896139BEB882
      4CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFFB8824CFF8E643AC50705030A000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050401076D4E
      2E99B7814CFEB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB8824CFFB882
      4CFF72512F9F0605020900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000251A0E336D4E2E999E7042DCB6814CFDB27E4AF79E7041DB71502E9C271C
      1036000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000000000000000424D3E000000000000003E000000
      2800000040000000100000000100010000000000800000000000000000000000
      000000000000000000000000FFFFFF00F00F000000000000C003000000000000
      8001000000000000800100000000000001800000000000000180000000000000
      0180000000000000018000000000000001800000000000000180000000000000
      0000000000000000018000000000000080010000000000008001000000000000
      C003000000000000F00F00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
      000000000000}
  end
  object PopupMenu1: TPopupMenu
    Images = ilMenus
    Left = 24
    Top = 96
    object menuitem1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Menu Item 1'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
    object menuitem2: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Menu Item 2'
      ImageIndex = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't happen to me in Delphi 10.4, Windows 7.

Comment: Are you using high DPI or VCL styles? Actually, this feels like a DPI scaling issue.

Comment: I have now included the Manifest settings from the Project Options: See the edited question.

Comment: The misalignment happens both on a HighDPI monitor and on a LowDPI monitor.

Comment: This is a screenshot from an IDE popup menu: https://www.screencast.com/t/YbOrG6ZC You can see that here the icons are correctly aligned.

Comment: I've tried out ALL DPI AWARENESS settings in Project Options -> Manifest Page: The problem still persists.

Comment: "_screenshot from an IDE popup menu_" - it's definitly a different font size and also looks like a different font, too. Also the background colors differ, so both are drawn differently. What happens without runtime themes?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Can you please show a screenshot of how the popup menu in the attached test project looks on your computer?

Comment: Sure: My work computer (Windows 10, Delphi 11, 100% DPI): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOqgL.png

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you, that looks better aligned than on my computer. From where exactly do you read your "100% DPI" value? Would you mind trying out this example with another (higher) DPI value? Thank you.

Comment: @user1580348: Windows settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJEsC.png

Comment: 200%: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl5rB.png

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Here are my "Advanced scaling settings" in Windows 10: https://www.screencast.com/t/snqbr88jNhNH

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand And here are my "Scale and layout" settings: https://www.screencast.com/t/0Aan1pmPO

Comment: @user1580348, have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue, the project compiled correctly on previous versions of Delphi.